# Nginx: Proxy redirect to TEST env

Tags: nginx, docker, meteor

I am trying to write an `nginx.conf` which will redirect to port 3001 where `meteor.js` TEST env is of my EC2 instance. If user types "xxx.xxxx.com/test". Redirection isn't working and it searches pages from my `meteor.js` app.

`Nginx` and `meteor.js` app are in `docker` containers.

*nginx.conf:*

```
events{

}

http{}
    server {
        listen *:80;
        server_name xxxxx.xxxx.com www.xxxxx.xxxx.com;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://xxxxx.xxxx.com:3000;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }

        location /test/ {
            proxy_pass http://xxxxx.xxxx.com:3001;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
    }
}
```

How to make a proper redirection(I am very new to nginx). Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please use the term proxy instead of redirect, since redirect implies HTTP redirect which is something else.

Answer (score 1):

Move `location /test/` above `location /`. That should do the trick.
With your cureent setup, requests with `/test` will be matched first in `location /`, and nginx will never look into other locations.

Comment: `/` - is for PROD. How PROD(port 3000) will be available? I need those 2 to be available at the same time

Comment: I got your point. `location / {
            proxy_pass http://studio.accenture.com:3000;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

            location /test/ {
                proxy_pass http://studio.accenture.com:3001;
                proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            }
        }`

Comment: It still tries to find a page called "test" in PROD app